# Why does my matrix look so vertically spaced apart?

Tags: spacing, matrices

In my document I use the code

```
\begin{equation}
M \ = \ \left[  \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right]
\end{equation}
```

and the output gives me the following goofy looking matrix (with too much vertical spacing!):

[image]

How to I make the matrix with normal vertical spacing?

I am using the the command `\linespread{1.5}` for the whole text, and I suspect this has something to do with it.

Comment: if you use a command to increase line spacing by 50% then lines will be spaced apart more. Rather than use that directly you could try using a package such as setspace that tries to undo the damage by locally resetting the spacing in math and footnotes etc. (Please always provide a small but complete document that shows the problem, not just a fragment.)

Comment: B;t. w., did you try to  use the `bmatrix`environment, rather than adding the brackets by hand?

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}` this gives nice rezult ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Countermand `\linespread{1.5}` with

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66667}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66667}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will also affect `tabular`.